# how to add textChange Event In autoComplete TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I've problem in my page sample.aspx textbox effected by JavaScript autocomplete 
and textbox has event ontextchanged when i select any from autocomplete result  the event doesn't work,
ex: google search when select from autocomplete result it do event.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CUSMO1" 
             AutoPostBack="True" 
             runat="server" 
             Height="25px" Width="280px" 
             ontextchanged="CUSMO1_TextChanged" 
             AutoCompleteType="Enabled" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

How to Resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked ontextchanged event with autocomplete off?